# Gitlab diff between Merge Request Target branch and Source Branch in pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My use involves finding a diff between Merge Request and Master or Release branch (whichever branch I want to diff against) the MR will have `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH` set.

```
CHANGED_DIRS=$(git diff --name-only ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}...${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | xargs -L1 dirname | uniq | cut -d'/' -f1 |tail -n+2 | uniq)
```

But it seems that gitlab doesn't recognize the Merge request target branch diff and gives this output.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master...source': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

How do I find the diff (which are directories).
Appreciate help !

Comment: Did you run `git fetch` first?

Comment: no - but `git fetch` what ? By default gitlab first init the repo and does the git add remote and checkout the branch (that is merge request branch) . Do you mean I should `git fetch origin master` first before diff ?

Comment: `get fetch` by itself, without arguments, it will fetch all branches. `By default gitlab first init the repo and does the git add remote and checkout the branch (that is merge request branch)` No, kind of, gitlab-ci ends up on detached head without branch checkout, but it depends on configuration. There's even a default number of commits checked in project configuration, I think default is 50.

Comment: ok still got the same error , I am surprised how it works locally but not in gitlab ci  , strange ``` * [new branch]      master        -> origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...whatever': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. ```

Comment: But yes git fetch did got all branches correctly. so locally I assume it must have the same structure as my local

Comment: Try `git checkout master` and `git pull` also.

Comment: `git fetch && git checkout ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME} && git pull` , this worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a *Git* issue, but rather a GitLab-CI issue.  However, these particular issues crop up in multiple CI/CD systems, always with the same general reason:

- Making a full clone of a large repository is slow.
- CI systems often start by cloning a repository.
- Hence, CI systems often start by making a *less-than-full* clone of the repository.
- Git offered just two ways to do this in the past:<sup>1</sup> *shallow clones* and *single-branch clones*.  In fact, they tend to go together: making a shallow clone, with `git clone --depth number`, also makes a single-branch clone unless you forcibly override Git's default by adding `--no-single-branch` as well.

Now, the *clone command* in any given CI/CD system may be controllable, or may be done *by* the CI/CD system *before* any software knobs that are available to you-as-a-developer are provided.  If you can affect the *command*, that's usually the way to go, but if not, you may still be able to correct the problem by running additional Git commands (this again depends on the CI/CD system):

- `git remote set-branches --add` allows you to add various branches to an otherwise single-branch clone;
- `git fetch --depth number`, `git fetch --deepen number`, and `git fetch --unshallow` are three ways to alter the depth of an existing shallow clone, or remove the depth restrictions entirely.

If your CI/CD system makes a shallow, single-branch clone, and you need a deeper clone with more remote-tracking names, you can get that using `git remote` and/or `git fetch`.

As I haven't used GitLab's CI system, I cannot provide a recipe here, but based on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260856/gitlab-diff-between-merge-request-target-branch-and-source-branch-in-pipeline#comment120643631_68260856), it sounds like they use `--depth 50` by default.  If you have a depth knob, setting it to zero (`0`) is the usual way to disable the `--depth` argument, which also disables the single-branch-ness.

Do note that regardless of how the system clones your repository, you will generally have only one *branch* name, or perhaps even none (detached HEAD) when cloning via tag.  A full clone will have a full set of *remote-tracking names*, while a single-branch clone will have only one remote-tracking name until you use `git remote` to adjust this and run a subsequent `git fetch` to add more remote-tracking names.

With GitHub Actions, the `v2` checkout makes a shallow single-branch clone by default, while the `v1` checkout makes a full clone.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is now a third method, the so-called *partial clone* with *promisor remotes*.  This is arguably the right way for a CI system to do the trick, but partial clones are not very good yet, for a lot of reasons, so this probably has to wait for improvements to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks @torek , I did exactly the depth on fetch so now I do `git fetch --depth 30` for my master/release branches. The problem here was more on Gitlab exactly as in your Merge Requests(i.e. Pull requests) they mark this as a new `refs/merge_requests/:id/` AND if you want to do `git diff merge_request....master` it doesn't recognize the master because it think there is only one branch , so on the container where the CI is running I had to locally fetch and clone the master/release branch to get a proper diff for me to work . But your answer is perfect on clone.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who already mentioned, this is because GitLab-CI does a shallow clone and not a full clone. However, rather than engineering a way to do a full clone or using remote comparisons, I use an inbuilt variable in GitLab-CI : `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA`.

To get the files use :
`git diff --name-only ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA}`

CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA - The base SHA of the merge request diff. [Ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this error by changing the command from

`git diff --name-only ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}...${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`

to

`git diff --name-only remotes/origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}...remotes/origin/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`.

It seems that the gitlab runner doesn't have any local branches. So we have to tell it to compare the difference between remote branches.